# About w3c validation and appending code

Tags: html, validation, w3c, w3c-validation

I've got interesting question. I'm building automatic monitoring system which checks if all my sites (over one domain) are W3C valid. The problem is, that I add daily content from other databases, which contains HTML. So, site which is valid on my website, after adding content from outside database can become not valid.

My question is:

If I will validate code from outside database and it will be valid, can I add it to my site and be sure that site will be still valid?

Simple question: W3C VALID HTML + W3C VALID HTML is always valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on many factors, and it may be the case that it will always result in valid HTML for you, but without having more details about your system, this can only be answered generally:

**No.**

---

To prove it, here’s a simple HTML5 example:

Your page has this valid `body`:

```html
<h1>Your site</h1>
<nav>…</nav>
<main>…</main>
<footer>…</footer>
```

The external database contains this valid snippet:

```html
<main>
  <p>…</p>
</main>
```

No matter where you insert this snippet, it will result in an invalid page because [there can only be one `main` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/grouping-content.html#the-main-element):

> Authors must not include more than one `main` element in a document.

---

Another obvious case:

Both, your page and the snippet from the external database, have an element with `id="a"`. Invalid, because the [ID must be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/dom.html#the-id-attribute) per page.